# Logitech Touchpad T650 losing configuration when switching user in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, logitech-mouse

I use [Logitech Wireless Rechargeable Touchpad T650](http://support.logitech.com/product/touchpad-t650) in my PC that runs Windows 10. Whenever someone else logs in to the PC with different user without me logging out (user switching), and then I switch back to my account, the touchpad would behave as if its driver is not installed: it doesn't recognize one finger, two finger, three finger tap, doesn't recognize swipe, no acceleration, etc.

This problem has been [known since 2012 with Windows 8](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/Touchpad-T650-Win8-User-switching-problems/td-p/912942) and it doesn't look like Logitech is going to fix it any time soon.

One brute force way to get back the tap and swipe recognition is to log out and then log in again, but this workaround is too cumbersome.

Any other quicker workaround?

Answer (score 0):

[One person in Logitech forum](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/Touchpad-T650-Win8-User-switching-problems/td-p/912942) shared he managed to regain the touchpad functionalities by exiting the Mouse and Keyboard Settings from system tray or closing SetPoint.exe from Task Manager, and then restarting the SetPoint.exe from the start menu (labeled Mouse and Keyboard Settings).

I created a batch file to perform the two steps at once:

```
taskkill /im SetPoint.exe /f /t
start "" "C:\Program Files\Logitech\SetPointP\SetPoint.exe" /s
```

I put a shortcut to this batch file in start menu (`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`) so whenever the touchpad is acting up I can just open the start menu and run the batch file.